# C: var was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, scope

I am attempting to get my array wrapper class to compile, but I'm new to c++. I keep getting a series of relating to the last function:

Line 81
Invalid Use of template-name 'warray' without an arugment list

Line 81
ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'parameter' with not type

line 81
error expected ',' or '...' before < town

line 83
rhs was not declared in this scope

and finally, line 86
rhs was not declared in this scope

This function is so confusing, and I think I implemented it all correct.

IDK! Please help!

```
#ifndef WARRAY

#define WARRAY
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdexcept>

    template <typename T>

    class warray {
        private:
            unsigned int theSize;
            T* theData;
        public:
            //will default to a size of 10 - bump to 10 if below
            warray(unsigned int size = 10){
                if(size < 10){
                    size = 10;
                }

                theSize = size;
                theData = new T[theSize];
            }

            //copy
            warray(const warray &rhs):theSize(rhs.theSize){
                theData = new T[theSize];
                //use assignment*this = rhs;
                *this = rhs;
            }

            //assignment
            warray & operator=(const warray &rhs){
                //only resize array if lhs < than rhs//this also remedies
                if(theSize < rhs.theSize){
                    delete [] theData;
                    theData = new T[rhs.theSize];
                }
                theSize = rhs.theSize;
                for(unsigned int i = 0; i < theSize; ++i){
                    (*this);
                }
                return *this;
            }

            //destrctor
            ~warray(){
                delete [] theData;
            }

            //operator+ will concatenate two arrays should be const
            warray operator+(const warray &rhs) const{
                warray toRet(theSize + rhs.size);
                for(unsigned int i = 0; i < theSize; ++i){
                    toRet[i] = (*this)[i];
                }
                for(unsigned int i = 0; i < theSize; ++i){
                    toRet[i+theSize] = rhs[i];
                }
                return warray();
            }

            //operator[unsigned T index]
            //will index and allow access to requested element
            // - two versions, const and non-const
            T operator[](unsigned int index) const{
                if(index >= theSize){
                    throw std::out_of_range ("in operator [] ");
                }
                return theData[theSize];
            }

            //size
            unsigned int size() const{
                return theSize;
            }
    };

     std::ostream &operator<< (std::ostream &os, const warray&<T> rhs){
        os << "[ ";
        for(unsigned i = 0; i < rhs.size()-1; ++i){
            os << rhs[i] << " , ";
        }
        os << rhs[rhs.size() - 1] << " ]";
        return os;
    }

#endif
```

Comment: Yes, "T *theData [theSize];"  is wrong.  You have marked this as C++ ... I recommend you replace the two data attributes with a single vector.

Comment: As other have answered, your issue is how you declare `theData`. Also some other notes: Your `<<` operator should be declared `friend` and moved within class scope; also what does this line do: `for(unsigned int i = 0; i < theSize; ++i) { (*this); }` ..??? .. and lastly, not sure if this is an exercise but wouldn't it be more prudent to use a `std::vector` or one of the other sequence containers (that can then use other STL sequencing functions like `std::fill` and/or `insert`)??

Comment: Please don't edit your question so as to invalidate all the answers that were previously given. That will make it quite confusing for future visitors who want an answer to your new question.

Comment: @TheDark I'm sorry, I adjusted it for the issue and won't change

Comment: @TheDark maybe take a second look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have marked this as C++.

I recommend you change from:

```
class warray {
    private:
        unsigned int theSize;
        T* theData;
```

And perhaps try:

```
class warray {
    private:
        std::vector<T> theData;
```

What you call "theSize" is now available as theData.size().

To append values of T, use push_back().

If you desire, you can allocate a start size using theData.reserve(size), but not necessary.

Remove

```
delete [] theData;
```

because you no longer 'new'd it in the ctor.

The vector's dtor will be called automagically when your warray instance is dtor'd.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
       T *theData [theSize];
```

attempts to declare an array of pointers of size `theSize`, but `theSize` is not a constant and is not known at compile time. You also don't want an array of pointers to `T`, you want a pointer to an array of `T`.

change it to

```
       T *theData;
```

There are other problems with your code. e.g. your `<<` operator needs to be a template and I have no idea what `(*this)` is trying to achieve.

Note: I am assuming you are doing this for learning purposes and can't simply use a vector.

Edit: The "Invalid Use of template-name 'warray' without an argument list" error is caused by the `<<` operator not having `template<typename T>` in front of it. It needs this to make it a templated function.

Comment: To add, the `<<` operator could be declared `friend` and moved within class scope

Comment: @txtechhelp It *could*, but there'd be no point, as it only needs the public interface.

Answer (score 1):

Can't define theData this way:

```
T *theData[theSize];
```

defining the size of a static array with a variable is non-standard. Some compilers allow it, some don't. Best practice is not to do it so you don't get tripped up. As it is, the Size has no defined value at that point so even if your compiler did that trick, there is a ton of ka-boom potential.

Fortunately, based on the rest of the code, you don't need to. You keep defining the size of the array yourself, so:

```
T *theData;
```

Should do you just fine.